# Fill Arrow HEad with Colour GDI+

Tags: windows, gdi+

I wanted to make a arrow head with filled colour 
so i created a grahics path and call draw fill

```
Brush *brush=new SolidBrush(Color::Blue);

Pen *myPen1 = new Pen(Color::Red, 2);
GraphicsPath *cappath=new GraphicsPath;

cappath->AddLine(-5,0,5,0);
cappath->AddLine(-5,0,0,5);
cappath->AddLine(0,5,5,0);
graphics.FillPath(brush,cappath);
CustomLineCap path(NULL,cappath);

myPen1->SetCustomEndCap(&path);
```

But it create a blue path near the origin.How to fill blue colour in cap

Answer (score 0):

1. GDI can fill only **closed convex polygons** correctly

   - polygon is defined by set of vertexes (points)
   - in correct order
2. GDI+ is unknown to me

   - but from your code you set polygon as set of lines instead of points and not in correct order
   - so try to change order of points to form the closed convex polygon this is what I mean:

   [image: polygon lines]

   - Black is your current code and Green is closed convex polygon

     ```
     cappath->AddLine( 5,0,-5,0);
     cappath->AddLine(-5,0, 0,5);
     cappath->AddLine( 0,5, 5,0);
     ```
   - if it is not working either try find how to add points to path instead of lines
   - or use GDI polygon

[notes]

- some features can interfere with polygon filling
- for example cull face can reject polygons in not the right order (CW/CCW)
- GDI does not have such thing but GDI+ ???
- just to be sure try also reverse all points
- Also do you have Solid Brush enabled ?